# How to pass Observable emissions to MutableSharedFlow?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

well, I have an Observable, I’ve used asFlow() to convert it but doesn’t emit.
I’m trying to migrate from Rx and Channels to Flow, so I have this function

```
override fun processIntents(intents: Observable<Intent>) {
     intents.asFlow().shareTo(intentsFlow).launchIn(this)
}
```

`shareTo()` is an extension function which does `onEach { receiver.emit(it) }`, `processIntents` exists in a base ViewModel, and `intentsFlow` is a `MutableSharedFlow`.

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.shareTo(receiver: MutableSharedFlow<T>): Flow<T> {
    return onEach { receiver.emit(it) }
}
```

I want to pass emissions coming from the `intents` Observable to `intentsFlow`, but it doesn’t work at all and the unit test keeps failing.

```
@Test(timeout = 4000)
fun `WHEN processIntent() with Rx subject or Observable emissions THEN intentsFlow should receive them`() {
    return runBlocking {

        val actual = mutableListOf<TestNumbersIntent>()
        val intentSubject = PublishSubject.create<TestNumbersIntent>()


        val viewModel = FlowViewModel<TestNumbersIntent, TestNumbersViewState>(
            dispatcher = Dispatchers.Unconfined,
            initialViewState = TestNumbersViewState()
        )

        viewModel.processIntents(intentSubject)


        intentSubject.onNext(OneIntent)
        intentSubject.onNext(TwoIntent)
        intentSubject.onNext(ThreeIntent)

        viewModel.intentsFlow.take(3).toList(actual)

        assertEquals(3, actual.size)
        assertEquals(OneIntent, actual[0])
        assertEquals(TwoIntent, actual[1])
        assertEquals(ThreeIntent, actual[2])
    }
}
```

> test timed out after 4000 milliseconds
> org.junit.runners.model.TestTimedOutException: test timed out after
> 4000 milliseconds

Comment: Please provide the `shareTo` implementation.  It's not clear what `receiver` refers to.

Comment: @JulianA. I've updated the post with shareTo() implementation

Comment: On which line the test fails ? @MohamedIbrahim

Comment: @ZulqurnainJutt it times out always, have added the error message

Comment: use runBlocking{} or runBlockingTest{} @MohamedIbrahim

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
val ps = PublishSubject.create<Int>()
val mf = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
val pf = ps.asFlow()
    .onEach {
        mf.emit(it)
    }
launch {
    pf.take(3).collect()
}
launch {
    mf.take(3).collect {
        println("$it") // Prints 1 2 3
    }
}
launch {
    yield() // Without this we suspend indefinitely
    ps.onNext(1)
    ps.onNext(2)
    ps.onNext(3)
}
```

We need the `take(3)`s to make sure our program terminates, because  `MutableSharedFlow` and `PublishSubject -> Flow` collect indefinitely.

We need the `yield` because we're working with a single thread and we need to give the other coroutines an opportunity to start working.

---

#### Take 2

This is *much* better.  Doesn't use `take`, and cleans up after itself.

After emitting the last item, calling `onComplete` on the `PublishSubject` terminates `MutableSharedFlow` collection.  This is a convenience, so that when this code runs it terminates completely.  It is not a requirement.  You can arrange your Job termination however you like.

Your code never terminating is not related to the emissions never being collected by the `MutableSharedFlow`.  These are separate concerns.  The first is due to the fact that neither a flow created from a `PublishSubject`, nor a `MutableSharedFlow`, terminates on its own.  The `PublishSubject` flow will terminate when `onComplete` is called.  The `MutableSharedFlow` will terminate when the coroutine (specifically, its `Job`) collecting it terminates.

The `Flow` constructed by `PublishSubject.asFlow()` drops any emissions if, at the time of the emission, collection of the `Flow` hasn't suspended, waiting for emissions.  This  introduces a race condition between being ready to collect and code that calls `PublishSubject.onNext()`.

This, I believe, is the reason why flow collection isn't picking up the `onNext` emissions in your code.

It's why a `yield` is required right after we launch the coroutine that collects from `psf`.

```
val ps = PublishSubject.create<Int>()
val msf = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
val psf = ps.asFlow()
    .onEach {
        msf.emit(it)
    }
val j1 = launch {
    psf.collect()
}

yield() // Use this to allow psf.collect to catch up

val j2 = launch {
    msf.collect {
        println("$it") // Prints 1 2 3 4
    }
}

launch {
    ps.onNext(1)
    ps.onNext(2)
    ps.onNext(3)
    ps.onNext(4)
    ps.onComplete()
}
j1.invokeOnCompletion { j2.cancel() }
j2.join()
```

Comment: I can't add take() on the ps.asFlow() , this exists on the production code, but will try to use takeWhile { isActive }

Comment: `take` is just one way to terminate these otherwise non-terminating flows.  It's used here for simplicity.  There are others, such as completing or cancelling the job of the coroutine that does the collecting.  In production code, it's more likely you'd do something like that.